calculating over the Hodge operator in a two form in $\Bbb R ^3$
If $w$ is a $k$-form in $\Bbb R ^n$, we define a $n-k$ form by
$$\ast(w)=\sum a_{i_1, \dots, i_k} \ast(dx_{i_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{i_{k}})=\sum a_{i_1, \dots, i_k} (-1)^{\sigma}(dx_{j_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{j_{n-k}})$$
from where $\sigma=0, 1$ if the permutation $(i_1, \dots, i_k, j_1, \dots, j_{n-k})$ is even or odd respectively ($i_1 < \cdots < i_k$, $j_1 < \cdots < i_{n-k}$)
I want to compute $\ast(a_{12}dx_{1} \wedge dx_{2}+a_{13}dx_{1} \wedge dx_{3} + a_{23} dx_{2} \wedge dx_{3})=a_{12}\ast(dx_{1}\wedge dx_{2})+a_{13} \ast(dx_{1} \wedge dx_{3})+a_{23} \ast(dx_{2} \wedge dx_{3})$
For $\ast(dx_{1}\wedge dx_{2})=(-1)^{\sigma} (dx_{3})$, in this case we can factor the permutation into an even number of product of transpositions $(123)=(13)(12)$ and $\ast(dx_{1}\wedge dx_{2})=(-1)^{0} (dx_{3})=dx_3$
But I have doubts about $\ast(dx_{1} \wedge dx_{3})$ because I also get an even number of products and the book suggests me that
$$a_{12}\ast(dx_{1}\wedge dx_{2})+a_{13} \ast(dx_{1} \wedge dx_{3})+a_{23} \ast(dx_{2} \wedge dx_{3})=a_{12} dx_3 -a_{13}dx_2+a_{23}dx_1$$
Maybe I'm taking the permutation wrong, or I don't see the difference in the results, any suggestions?

You are misstating the sign criterion. The question is: What is the sign of the permutation taking $132$ to $123$? Thus, one transposition is required. Ultimately, you want $dx_i\wedge dx_j\wedge\star(dx_i\wedge dx_j) = dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge dx_3$. Note that all $3$-cycles are even permutations, so that isn't the point.

I understand, I saw it as the number of products of transpositions, but just look at the number of transpositions, in our case for $123$ to $123$ it takes zero transpositions, so it takes a positive sign, for $132$ to $123$ it takes one transposition so there is a negative sign; finally for $231$ to $123$ it would take two transpositions, hence the sign is positive. That is what I understand with your comment, is it completely true what I say?

Yes, the permutation taking $132$ to $123$ is $(23)$.
